# How to center the "featured products" (prestashop)?

Tags: prestashop

I have a big problem with arranging the text from "featured products" in prestashop. First of all, I want the title to be on two lines and centered. I've tried several methods, but with no success. Second, I want "short description" to have more characters and be centered as well. 
I've posted below the link to the site and an image of how I would like it to look. Do you know what line should I change or what I need to do?

http://www.3bwine.com/CRISTY/prestashop/index.php

http://oi58.tinypic.com/1608m10.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple CSS "problem". Css for described changes come from two files.

.../prestashop/themes/default/css/golbal.css
.../prestashop/modules/homefeatured/homefeatured.css - this is not very important but may or may not interfear with some of our changes

To align your title they way you showed on your image I reccomend to add these lines of code to your global.css file ( as you dont have any VERY unique classes on your p or a elements we will be targeting them from a bit further)

```
div#featured-products_block_center div.block_content ul li p.s_title_block a{
    text-align:right;
    width: 150px; // set as big/small as you want yoru heading title to display, you can play around with it. This should push the title on two lines, but if your title is chagining all the time in lenght then it might not be useful.
    font-size: 22px; // should overwrite the current font-size, make as big/small as you need 
}
```

To align description the way you need add this line to global.css file

```
div#featured-products_block_center div.block_content ul li div.product_desc a{
    text-align:right;
    margin-bottom: 20px; // you can play around with it , this pushes your price further away from the text 
}
```

To change the lenght of your short description go to ../prestashop/modules/homefeatured/homefeatured.tpl and locate something similar to this

```
{$product.description_short|strip_tags|truncate:65:'...'}
```

And there change the truncate to whatever you need. ( changes the lenght of your " short description"). Number is in characters.

BR's